# How to set up Raspberry Pi 4B as a I2C slave

Tags: python, c++, c, raspberry-pi, psoc

I'm trying to set up a RPi 4B to work as an I2C slave with PSoC (4.4) - CY8C5888LTI-LP097.
Below is my code to set up the slave address on the Pi.

```
import pigpio

pi = None
slave_addr = 0x13

def i2cInterrupt():
   global pi
   global slave_addr
   status, bytes_read, data = pi.bsc_i2c(slave_addr) 

   if bytes_read:
      print(data)

pi = pigpio.pi()
int_handler = pi.event_callback(pigpio.EVENT_BSC, i2cInterrupt)
pi.bsc_i2c(slave_addr)
```

I have followed this example: http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#bsc_i2c
however, not detecting anything when I run

```
$ i2cdetect -y 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you loopback any i2c master GPIOs to the slave GPIOs. On RPi4 you'll have to jumper GPIO 2-3 to GPIO 10-11, respectively.